# FancyBox requested content cannot be loaded. Using handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, fancybox-2

I'm trying to load some text from a div into a fancybox, this works fine when I name the divs by hand, e.g

```
<a class='fancybox' href="#inline">Lightbox</a>
<div id='inline' style="display: none;">test</div>
```

However when the id's are named using handle bars,

```
<a class='fancybox' href="#{{this}}">Lightbox</a>
<div id='{{this}}' style='display: none;'>test</div>
```

I get the error

> "The requested content cannot be loaded.
>   Please try again later."

Looking in Developer Tools I can see that the id's are identical

[Screenshot from developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBlIs.png)

Im using the following code to load the FancyBox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  fitToView : false,
  autoSize : true,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  type        : 'inline',
 });
});
```

Comment: can you use "Media-Ninja" instead of "Media Ninja" you know you have two different ids there.

Comment: @S.Gholizadeh adding a dash to the names worked perfectly, thanks for that. I completely forgot that you cant have spaces in id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to screen shot and as this fix the issue:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#Media Ninja">...</a>
<div id="Media Ninja" style="display: none;">
```

should be:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#Media-Ninja">...</a>
<div id="Media-Ninja" style="display: none;">
```

which means you should check the id variable to be one specific id pointing to a specific div tag.